# Pointer-to-member that points to derived member

Tags: c++

Is there a syntax that allows for a pointer-to-member that references a derived member instance, that is the member itself rather than the containing object.

If I do the following:

```
struct Base1
{
    int m;
};
struct Derived : Base1
{
    int n;
};
struct Base2
{
    Base1 b;
    Derived d;
};

void foo()
{
    Base1 Base2::*ptr1 = &Base2::b ;// okay
    Base1 Base2::*ptr2 = &Base2::d; // error
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Derived Base2::* ' to 'Base1 Base2::* '
note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Is there a reasonable way to do this without needing a cast? (I would prefer not to use templates here if possible because the actual type would need to be saved beyond the current call chain).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I'm not familiar with the syntax on each line in `foo()`. I tried it with `gcc` and it compiles fine so I'm assuming it's valid, but what does `Base1 Base2::*ptr1` specifically mean?

Comment: @Dai - Those are [pointers to members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members). And GCC is being permissive on your end. Try with `-pedantic`.

Comment: Nope. Runtime polymorphism does not apply to pointers to members. You need to use the exact type (or `auto`.) So whatever is it you're trying to do here, it looks like you need to refactor it.

Comment: The second line of foo does NOT compile - .  g++ reports: "error: invalid conversion from ‘Derived Base2::*’ to ‘Base1 Base2::*’ [-fpermissive]"; clang++ reports: "error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'Base1 Base2::*' with an rvalue of type 'Derived Base2::*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your problem is that you access a derived member object. It is that you declare it of the wrong type. Your second pointer should be declared as follows:

Derived Base2::*ptr2 = &Base2::d; // OK

Are you specifically trying to apply base pointer to derived class semantics for members to pointers ? That does not work, it must match the exact type. You can't even perform any of the trivial conversions, for example declare a pointer to void which points at a pointer to int member.

If you wish, you can perform any common access through a common base class pointer by using a new assignment after you bind the pointer-to-members to their instances.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this violates the "no templates" policy, but a `std::variant` can be made to hold either pointer type.

```
using ptm_type = std::variant<Base1 Base2::*, Derived Base2::*>;
ptm_type ptr1 = &Base2::b ;// okay
ptm_type ptr2 = &Base2::d; // okay too
```

Since I assume you want to treat the `Base1` and `Derived` objects identically (why bother otherwise), you can then wrap your code in a call to `std::visit` for uniform access

```
std::visit([](auto& p1){
  // Do your thing
}, ptr1);
```

Though admittedly that's just another template in disguise.

Comment: Sorry, but variant seems like a really poor solution here, Base1 is in a DLL and has no way to know what the derived types may be as they may come from other DLLs or the final executable. And having multiple pointer types just to invoke virtual functions on the base portion seems very silly.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir - You aren't using pointers. You are using pointers to members. A different beast all-together. There's no getting around the type system on this, other than with a cast, and everything *that* entails.

Comment: I was afraid of that but thought I would toss it out and see if there was something I overlooked.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir - Well, to be honest I don't entirely follow your requirements. Maybe there is something that can be done if you incorporate more of them into your original question.